# Laravel Form Model Binding with File Upload is not working

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

I'm trying to upload file with form model binding in laravel 5.2. But it is not working I'm not getting file data in controller.

```
{!! Form::model($settings, ['route' => ['admin.settings.update', $settings->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'PATCH',  'fiels' => true  , 'id' => 'edit-settings']) !!}

<div class="form-group">

    {!!  Form::file('logo') !!}

</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

In Controller I've properly imported Input Facades and trying to get file object like this.

```
$image = Input::all('logo'); 
OR
$image = Input::file('logo');
```

But I'm getting name of the file and not total file object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your form model like with this, you misspelled the file name

```
{!!Form::model($settings, ['route' => ['admin.settings.update', $settings->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'method' => 'PATCH',  'files' => true  , 'id' => 'edit-settings']) !!}
```

then in your controller, do this,

`Input::file('logo');` Instead `Input::all('logo');` because `Input::all();` return all form inputs. so try this one `Input::file('logo');`